# Remove "Checkout" Button on sidebar when cart is empty

Tags: jquery, html, magento, php

I managed to remove "My Cart" and I thought this would also remove "Checkout" button that goes under it but it is still showing. Any ideas on how to get rid of the button when cart is empty? I have tried some "solutions" but none of them seem to work. I would really appreciate some help. Thank you very much.

This is sidebar.phtml found on "app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml"

```
?>
<?php if ($this->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()):?>
<?php $_cartQty1 = $this->getSummaryCount() ?>
<?php if ($_cartQty1 >0): ?>
<div class="block block-cart">
    <?php $_cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount() ?>
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('My Cart') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
    <?php if ($_cartQty>0): ?>
        <div class="summary">
            <?php if ($_cartQty==1): ?>
                <p class="amount"><?php echo $this->__('There is <a href="%s">1 item</a> in your cart.', $this->getUrl('checkout/cart')) ?></p>
            <?php else: ?>
                <p class="amount"><?php echo $this->__('There are <a href="%s">%s items</a> in your cart.', $this->getUrl('checkout/cart'), $_cartQty) ?></p>
            <?php endif ?>
            <p class="subtotal">
                <?php if ($this->canApplyMsrp()): ?>
                    <span class="map-cart-sidebar-total"><?php echo $this->__('ORDER TOTAL WILL BE DISPLAYED BEFORE YOU SUBMIT THE ORDER'); ?></span>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Cart Subtotal:') ?></span> <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal()) ?>
                    <?php if ($_subtotalInclTax = $this->getSubtotalInclTax()): ?>
                        <br />(<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_subtotalInclTax) ?> <?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->getIncExcText(true) ?>)
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php if($_cartQty && $this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()): ?>
    <div class="actions">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_actions') ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?>" class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php $_items = $this->getRecentItems() ?>
    <?php if(count($_items)): ?>
        <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Recently added item(s)') ?></p>
        <ol id="cart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list">
        <?php foreach($_items as $_item): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('cart-sidebar', 'none-recursive')</script>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="empty"><?php echo $this->__('You have no items in your shopping cart.') ?></p>
    <?php endif ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
<?php endif;?>

<div class="sb-con"><a href="/blubackorder/" target="_blank"></a></div>
<div class="chOut"><a href="<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl('');?>">Checkout</a></div>
```

Comment: What part are you stuck with, you have the condition statement you need from removing My Cart, and you can see the Checkout link, what's the issue?

Comment: I have removed "My Cart" by adding  "<?php $_cartQty1 = $this->getSummaryCount() ?>
<?php if ($_cartQty1 >0): ?>" on third and fourth line but "Checkout" button is still showing, I want to be able to remove it too. I am not very good with PHP so it is hard for me.

Comment: Because checkout isn't within that `if` block. Either move the end of the block beyond the checkout link at the bottom, or copy the if block and wrap the checkout button with it.

Comment: that is because you still have this button outside of your `if(): endif;`, indeed you've put your `endif;` just above this button

Comment: Thank you very much Jon and b.enoit.be. Thumbs up for you guys.

Answer (score -2):

Change the last line to this

```
<?php if(!count($_items)): ?>
<div class="chOut"><a href="<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl('');?>">Checkout</a></div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Look again, `$_items` isn't going to help.